# Run the program when the computer is on

Tags: installation

I want to make my program to be run automatically every time when the computer is up.
How can i achieve this? I'm creating the installer by wix and I have the wpf application.
Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry,I can't get u. You mean to run the application by windows service?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways, some more complicated than others:

1. **Startup folder shortcut**
2. **Scheduled task launch**
3. **Service**
4. **Shell extension**

The latter two are quite complicated, and a shell extension is a bit mad since it may crash the whole desktop if there is a bug. There are also other ways to make an application launch on startup, but I can't recall right now.

The simplest is probably to create a shortcut in the system-wide Startup folder. The windows installer property is **StartupFolder**. Then install "per-machine" by setting ALLUSERS = 1.